polyglossia does bad hypenation
I'm using xelatex and polyglossia:
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\setmainlanguage{hungarian}


\title{Teszt}

\begin{document}

egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb egyszerűbb 

\end{document}

This does not do hypenation at all, which results in a very messy right text on the right side. Here is an example:

If I remove \setdefaultlanguage{hungarian} then it starts doing hypenation, but it is bad, here is an example:

it should be egy-sze-rűbb and not egysz-erűbb
What am I missing?

Your question is missing a complete example that can be used for a test.

What do you mean by remove \setdefaultlanguage{hungarian}?  The obvious meaning would mean that you're getting hyphenation for US English, so of course ti would be bad.

Unless your TeX distribution hasn't been updated in a decade or more, it's not necessary to specify \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}.

minimal working example added

@nagylzs Can you show your .log file? I get hyphens if I try your first example https://i.sstatic.net/8MwiKEjT.png

I can but it is 17KB. How should I put it here? Maybe this will do https://pastebin.com/nnXqWdS6

In the logs I see Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for 'hungarian' but I have no idea why hypenation patterns were not loaded.

probably there are not there, that can happen when using tex systems from linux distribution. Check if there is some language package that you can install.

What do you get running the commands kpsewhich polyglossia.sty and kpsewhich gloss-hungarian.ldf ?

kpsewhich polyglossia.sty returns /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty and kpsewhich gloss-hungarian.ldf returns /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-hungarian.ldf . I have installed latex with apt install texlive-full on ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (jammy)
